# Primefaces- append dollar symbol and format comma of the currency value in input text

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a form with primefaces input text(p:inputText).Many of the input text values are of the type currency in dollars.When i try to use  ,it mandates the user to include $ symbol prepended to the value.Is there any way using which on blur of the field the dollar symbol is prepended and the number gets formatted with proper commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at primefaces extensions. They have one component for doing this. This would be the code:

```
<pe:inputNumber id="Input2" value="#{inputNumberController.input}" symbol=" $" symbolPosition="s"  
                decimalSeparator="," thousandSeparator="." />
```

This is the [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/views/inputNumber.jsf)